# Как организовать лицензирование своей программы по типу key collector, fast trust?

Tags: .net, защита, лицензирование

Здравствуйте
Есть идея написания программы, и уверен она будет востребована.
И программу нужно будет продавать. 1 лицензия на 1 комп.

Понравилась идея key collector, fast trust. 
Там пользователь генерирует уникальный код по **Hardware ID** и отсылает разработчику, он в ответ на основе кода генерирует файл лицензии **lic.license** и отдает покупателю. И покупатель закидает в папку с программой и все отлично работает.

Планирую писать при помощи devexpress, как fast trust. 
Лицензия будет не постоянная, а временная, на год, после года - обновление лицензии.

Как это можно организовать? Может есть какие то готовые решения?

Comment: Если программа действительно будет востребована, то денежные средства и усилия, направленные на ее защиту могут оказаться напрасными, т.к. её все равно сломают. Если программа будет действительно стоящая, то пользователь купит лицензию. Если же он не готов платить за вашу программу, то он её не купит, как бы защищена она не была. А если кто то будет использовать взломанную версию вашей программы, так ничего страшного, значит она популярна у юзеров, а у популярного софта продаж больше)

Comment: LANSELOT, было бы отлично если бы Вы что то по теме добавили)

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что .NET - тотальная бяка в плане защиты.

Хотите нормальную защиту - выносите часть не критически важного для быстродействия функционала (в том числе и функции защиты\лицензирования) в нативный код. Нативный код уже накрывайте The Enigma Protector (опция: Virtual Machine), т.е. в нативных функциях и процедурах указываются маркеры *стандартной виртуальной машины* (доступна для x64\x32), или RISC (она доступна только для x32) энигмы.

А оставшуюся часть .NET кода - накрываем обфуксатором (.NET Reactor например), а лучше парочкой.

Думаю не нужно напоминать что протекторы\обфуксаторы нужны - Лицензионные!

p.s. .NET Native мы так и не дождемся видимо... Думаю с ним дела пошли бы в разы проще....

p.p.s. так же хотелось бы посмотреть другие варианты защиты для расширения кругозора. Выносить основной функционал на сервер - не предлагать, это реализуемо не во всех приложениях.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37059/discussion-on-answer-by-alexis------).